# How to remove space in front of each element in array?

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
String n= "   Hello world This is me , Hello";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n.trim().split(" ")));
```

output

```
[Hello, world, This, is, me, ,, Hello]
```

what I want is (space before each element should be removed)

```
[Hello,world,This,is,me,,,Hello]
```

Comment: Those spaces are added by `Arrays.toString`, they are not part of your `String[]`. You can create your custom output by copying what `Arrays.toString` does and leaving out the space. Or write your own code such as `Arrays.stream(arr).collect(Collectors.joining(",")); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you have to implement your own toString(). The Arrays.toString() method appends ", " after each element of the array. You have to change it like below. Here you will be using toString() method in your own class instead of toString method in Arrays class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String n= "   Hello world This is me , Hello";
        System.out.println(toString(n.trim().split(" ")));
         
        
    }
    
      public static String toString(String[] a) {
            if (a == null)
                return "null";

            int iMax = a.length - 1;
            if (iMax == -1)
                return "[]";

            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            b.append('[');
            for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
                b.append(String.valueOf(a[i]));
                if (i == iMax)
                    return b.append(']').toString();
                b.append(",");
            }
        }
```